# Pandas filtering by date column with mixed columns data types

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas dataframe similar to the one below with mixed columns data types (strings, datatime, integers) what I wanted to do was filtering the rows to get the last record by date of the combination of Company and Model.

I've searched among many filtering / groupby solution what I was able to get were the rows I needed but many columns were missing (see the groupby below). I've read about the nuisance of columns in pandas, I tried using groupby to generate a mask  to use in the original dataframe but I failed. I don't know how to proceed to have the same result but with all the  original columns.

```py
data = {'Company': ['Mercedes', 'Fiat', 'Ferrari', 'Mercedes', 'Volkswagen'],
        'Model': ['Class A', 'Punto', 'GTO', 'Class A', 'Polo'],
        'User': ['Mario', 'Paolo', 'Filippo', 'Andrea', 'Giuseppe'],
        'Rented on': ['2017-04-02', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-22', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-02'],
        'Kms': [2200, 3000, 110, 2400, 3000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df.groupby(['Company', 'Model'])['Rented on'].last().reset_index()
```

```py
# What I have
      Company   Kms    Model   Rented on      User
0    Mercedes  2200  Class A  2017-04-02     Mario
1        Fiat  3000    Punto  2017-05-01     Paolo
2     Ferrari   110      GTO  2017-05-22   Filippo
3    Mercedes  2400  Class A  2017-08-01    Andrea
4  Volkswagen  3000     Polo  2017-08-02  Giuseppe
# What I get
      Company    Model   Rented on
0     Ferrari      GTO  2017-05-22
1        Fiat    Punto  2017-05-01
2    Mercedes  Class A  2017-08-01
3  Volkswagen     Polo  2017-08-02
# What I want
      Company   Kms    Model   Rented on      User
0        Fiat  3000    Punto  2017-05-01     Paolo
1     Ferrari   110      GTO  2017-05-22   Filippo
2    Mercedes  2400  Class A  2017-08-01    Andrea
3  Volkswagen  3000     Polo  2017-08-02  Giuseppe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `transform` with [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df['Rented on'].eq(df.groupby(['Company', 'Model'])['Rented on'].transform('last'))]
```

---

```
      Company    Model      User   Rented on   Kms
1        Fiat    Punto     Paolo  2017-05-01  3000
2     Ferrari      GTO   Filippo  2017-05-22   110
3    Mercedes  Class A    Andrea  2017-08-01  2400
4  Volkswagen     Polo  Giuseppe  2017-08-02  3000
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, now I'll check better how does transform work.

Comment: @Variac it is not taking last date when tried with following input  ```data = {'Company': ['Mercedes', 'Fiat', 'Ferrari', 'Mercedes', 'Volkswagen'],
        'Model': ['Class A', 'Punto', 'GTO', 'Class A', 'Polo'],
        'User': ['Mario', 'Paolo', 'Filippo', 'Andrea', 'Giuseppe'],
        'Rented on': ['2017-08-02', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-22', '2017-04-01', '2017-08-02'],
        'Kms': [2200, 3000, 110, 2400, 3000]
        }```  does your data always have dates on ascending order?

Comment: I was just trying to understand how this solutions works and realized that it has not considered case where date is not sorted. It is not getting last record by date as user has asked for "get the last record by date" in question

Comment: @DevKhadka np, let me explain , you have duplicate dates in the example, the user has not mentioned what to do in such cases, the solution definately consideres last dates, try with `df.groupby(['Company', 'Model'])['Rented on'].transform('last')` and you will see that it has transformed the grouped dataframe into a series of last dates

Comment: ya, that may be the case

Answer (score 1):

use apply instead of last

```py
data = {'Company': ['Mercedes', 'Fiat', 'Ferrari', 'Mercedes', 'Volkswagen'],
        'Model': ['Class A', 'Punto', 'GTO', 'Class A', 'Polo'],
        'User': ['Mario', 'Paolo', 'Filippo', 'Andrea', 'Giuseppe'],
        'Rented on': ['2017-04-02', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-22', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-02'],
        'Kms': [2200, 3000, 110, 2400, 3000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Rented on"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Rented on"])

result = df.groupby(['Company', 'Model']).apply(lambda x: x[x["Rented on"]==x["Rented on"].max()] )
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
display(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but date now is converted in a number, @anky_91 method is more compact even if your is slighter more understandable.

Comment: you can remove ```df["Rented on"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Rented on"])``` this line to keep it as string. converting in datetime type will make it efficient in comparision and other operations